# Using filtered datatables in shiny

Tags: r, filter, datatable, datatables, shiny

I am new to `shiny` but was wondering if there is any way to store a **filtered datatable** (using the column filters) in a `R` object so that this filtered data can be passed to **histogram** and **plot functions**.

EDIT May 7, 15: Including the author's expanded explanation from comments

> I want the table to get filtered using the built-in column filters and
>   then want the plot to automatically adjust. I've already tried the DT
>   package but I don't like very much of the column filters that come
>   with this package as it is not possible (I think) to remove the
>   filters from a subset of the columns in the table

Comment: your question is still unclear. Do you want the data.table to get filtered using some inputs the user choose (like a value from a `selectInput` widget) and then your plot automatically adjusts?

Comment: if you are using the `DT` package, to render your DataTable `input$table_rows_all` holds the indices of the filtered rows. There is an example [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/)

Comment: I want the table to get filtered using the built-in column filters and then want the plot to automatically adjust. I've already tried the DT package but I don't like very much of the column filters that come with this package as it is not possible (I think) to remove the filters from a subset of the columns in the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just building up on @JasonAizkalns's example, you can hide some of the built-in column filters using jQuery. for example here the first two are hidden:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, filter="top",options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),callback=JS("
           //hide column filters for the first two columns
          $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
                $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()
              });"))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- input$tbl_rows_all
      hist(iris[filtered_data, "Sepal.Length"])
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [example](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/) suggested by @NicE is very helpful. I am including a minimal example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- input$tbl_rows_all
      hist(iris[filtered_data, "Sepal.Length"])
    })
  }
)
```

This will generate a histogram of `Sepal.Length` from the `iris` data set for the filtered data in the `DT::datatable`.

Note: This assumes the following versions of `DT` and `shiny`:

`DT_0.0.39         shiny_0.11.1.9005`

Comment: on my setup: Error: invalid number of 'breaks'