# ggplot with filtered data from datatable (DT) and reactive widgets to choose x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, datatable, shiny, dt

I would like to use the filtered data from datatable to create a ggplot. I implemented as well two widgets, which after filtering the datatable will allow user to choose x & y axis to display. After setting up the widgets and so on i got an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data_melt, filtered_data) : undefined columns selected
```

I have no idea why this happened.

my data example:

```
              Rundheit      Diff Charge  Ord..Nr.      Block.Nr. 
1               0.24        0.20 754331      738         1                             
2               0.26        0.21 783345      738         2          
3               0.25        0.15 795656      738         3          
4               NA          0.14 798431      738         4          
5               NA          0.12 799651      738         5          
6               0.24        NA   805454      738         6
```

**The NA values must stay** in my data

UI:

```
ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "WW"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "yaxis", 
                   label = "Y-axis (Diagramm)",
                   choices = list("Rundheit" = "Rundheit",
                                  "Diff" = "Diff"), 
                   selected = c("Rundheit"), multiple=TRUE),
    selectInput(inputId = "xaxis", 
                label = "X-axis (Diagramm)",
                choices = names(data_melt), 
                selected = "Block.Nr.")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(status = "primary", width = NULL, height = "1000px", 
        tabPanel(title="Tabelle filtern", div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 950px; position:relative;', 
                                                                 dataTableOutput("tabelle"))),
                    tabPanel("Diagramm", plotOutput("plot1")),
                    tabPanel("Histogramm", plotOutput("plot2"))))
  ))
```

Server:

```
      server <-  function(input, output, session) {

    output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({    
    datatable(data[, c("Rundheit", "Diff", "Charge.", "Ord..Nr.", "Block.Nr.")], class = 'cell-border stripe', 
                       rownames=FALSE, filter="top", 
options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"), list(bSortable = FALSE, targets = "_all"))), callback=JS("
                   //hide column filters for two columns
                    $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
                    $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()});", 
                    "var tips = ['Rundheit', 'Diff', 'Charge',
                    'Ord..Nr.', 'Block.Nr.'],
                    header = table.columns().header();
                    for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
                    $(header[i]).attr('title', tips[i]);}")) %>%
                formatStyle("Rundheit",  color = 'red', backgroundColor = 'lightyellow', fontWeight = 'bold')
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                filtered_data <- input$tabelle_rows_all
                data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data]    


            ggplot(data=data_filt, aes_string(x = input$xaxis, y = input$yaxis), environment = environment())+ geom_line(aes(group=1), size=1) +
                        theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), axis.title.x = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
             })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working, and **how i can define columns** then.

I have seen post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042456/using-filtered-datatables-in-shiny](http://Using%20filtered%20datatables%20in%20shiny)

However for the code:

```
[filtered_data, "name of the column"]
```

is not working by using for example:

```
data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data, ]

Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

And

```
Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

as well as:

```
data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data, input$xaxis]
```

and it gives an error (depending on the type of the column):

```
Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor
Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

and i need `input$yaxis` as well to be implemented...
Therefore i tried:

```
data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data, c(input$xaxis, input$yaxis)]
```

Than i got an error

```
Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

Just for the Info I played bit with this code, and even by specifying name of the column it throws an error and i cannot even specify more then one

I have tried things like:

```
[filtered_data, "Rundheit")

[filtered_data, c("Rundheit", "Diff")]
```

Thank You very much for any ideas

Comment: Your `renderPlot` is not closed. Please fix.

Comment: Sorry, i just copied my code not fully.. renderPlot is closed in my script

Comment: When asking a question, it is better to provide a minimum working example.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, sorry i am new here. I have just updated my post

Comment: Does this answer help?

Comment: Hello Mike, I'm going check the code on Monday at work, but it seems pretty good. Thanks so much and surely gonna update You on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code was a bit "messy", with a few compiler errors, some missing code, and I had to enter your data by hand. Not everyone would do that... I am also not sure where the `data` and `data_melt` stuff was supposed to happen, so I just went for `data_melt`. Anyway I got it to work, and I have to admit this is powerful and fascinating functionality. I hope it is what you want, although I did not see all of your error messages per-se.

Your main mistake was setting `rownames=F`, since the rownames are what the `input$tabelle_rows_all` uses to filter the table. I also added an `nrow` guard to the `ggplot` call to keep it from choking on empty dataframes.

Here is the working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

rr <- c(0.24,0.26,0.25,NA,NA,0.24)
dd <- c(0.20,0.21,0.15,0.14,0.12,NA)
cc <- c(74331,783345,795656,798431,799651,805454)
oo <- rep(738,6)
bb <- 1:6
data_melt <- data.frame(Rundheit=rr,Diff=dd,Charge.=cc,Ord..Nr.=oo,Block.Nr.=bb)


ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "WW"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "yaxis", 
                   label = "Y-axis (Diagramm)",
                   choices = list("Rundheit" = "Rundheit",
                                  "Diff" = "Diff"), 
                   selected = c("Rundheit"), multiple=TRUE),
    selectInput(inputId = "xaxis", 
                label = "X-axis (Diagramm)",
                choices = names(data_melt), 
                selected = "Block.Nr.")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(status = "primary", width = NULL, height = "1000px", 
             tabPanel(title="Tabelle filtern", 
              div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 950px; position:relative;', 
             dataTableOutput("tabelle"))),
             tabPanel("Diagramm", plotOutput("plot1")),
             tabPanel("Histogramm", plotOutput("plot2"))))
  ))    
server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({    
    datatable(data_melt[, c("Rundheit", "Diff", "Charge.", "Ord..Nr.", "Block.Nr.")], 
              class = 'cell-border stripe', 
              filter="top", 
              options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, 
                             columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"), 
                                          list(bSortable = FALSE, targets = "_all"))), 
              callback=JS("
                   //hide column filters for two columns
                    $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
                    $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()});
                     var tips = ['Rundheit', 'Diff', 'Charge',
                    'Ord..Nr.', 'Block.Nr.'],
                    header = table.columns().header();
                    for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
                    $(header[i]).attr('title', tips[i]);}")) %>%
      formatStyle("Rundheit",  color='red', backgroundColor='lightyellow', fontWeight='bold')
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    filtered_data <- input$tabelle_rows_all
    data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data,]  
    if (nrow(data_filt>0)){
      g <-ggplot(data=data_filt, aes_string( x=input$xaxis, y=input$yaxis), 
                                                environment=environment())+ 
        geom_line(aes(group=1), size=1) +
            theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), 
              axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), 
              axis.title.x = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
              axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
      return(g)
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here are a couple of screen shots to show it working:

[image]

Yielding:

[image]